# How to give Wine / Crossover games access to LAN?

Tags: wine, games, lan, crossover

I'm trying to do LAN gaming with Crossover for Linux, but my computer doesn't ever get found by other players in my network, neither does it find other players itself.

(I tried with 2 games, Battle for Middle Earth 2 and Anno 1602.)

Is there a general method for achieving LAN access for Wine?

Comment: If your question's been answered (which I assume it has since you gave the bounty), you should probably accept an answer.

Comment: None of the answers fixed my problem, that's why I did not give out the bounty. The site handed the half out itself because I started it. I'm still waiting for a solution, in fact.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to try [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/download.aspx) (unmanaged), since it creates a virtual LAN network. As far as Wine is concerned, I've only used Hamachi with Wine to play Diablo II TCP/IP, not LAN. However, I assume this would work, since I've gotten Minecraft LAN to work with computers out of my network using Hamachi.

---

So you'll want everyone you want to play LAN with to install Hamachi, and you all join a single network; Then, when you open a LAN game, if you connect using an IP, you'll want to use your Hamachi IP, which I believe usually is something like 5.x.x.x

Answer (score 2):

Your best best is to ask on the wine forums at winehq (it's the same people) or on the forums at crossover.

First, you need to make sure that you have real access to the LAN. Check your firewall, and make sure your not blocking any ports. Make sure that the port your trying gets used.

You can also experience problems with older games that try to access NICs directly or some such. However for most part wine just uses the network you have. It doesn't care if the packets are routed to the internet or 5 feet away. This could be very game specific.

Older DirectPlay games also have some problems. If you look at Anno 1602 for example you will find that dplay (networking) is a problem. [see the bug report](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6847). There is a workaround.  Download the dll files you need for dplay [better instructions here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=8357) and set them to use them by doing something like

`WINEDLLOVERRIDES="dplayx,dpnet,dpnhpast,dpwsockx=n" wine 1602.exe`

Keep in mind this is just one way to achieve this.

Comment: There's not anything that special between wine and crossover wine in this regard. You will need to setup the overrides in crossover instead of wine. However it's done exactly the same way.