# I am not able to find other people on my local network when playing Counter Strike 1.6

Tags: networking, server, wine, games, steam

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and the others have Windows. I am not able to see their server nor are they able to see my servers. I am also not able to find any internet servers.

I am using wine to run Counter Strike 1.6

However, I am able to connect directly to the host ip and join the game. This is why it's not similar to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211721)

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give Wine / Crossover games access to LAN?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/211721/how-to-give-wine-crossover-games-access-to-lan)

Answer (score -1):

try this command :

```
sudo iptables -R INPUT 5 -p udp -m udp --sport 26900:27030 --dport 1025:65355 -j ACCEPT
```

also you can read  : 
https://www.linode.com/docs/game-servers/launch-a-counter-strike-global-offensive-server-on-ubuntu-14-04